Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
I tried to install yolo but it returns an error saying I do not have enough disk space(ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OS Error: [Errno 28]
command used for install:
pip install ultralytics

information with command df -h:
   Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
tmpfs               392M    1,6M   390M   1%  /run
/dev/sda1            48G     28G    18G  62%  /
tmpfs               2,0G       0   2,0G   0%  /dev/shm
tmpfs               5,0M    4,0K   5,0M   1%  /run/lock
tmpfs               2,0G    351M   1,6G  18%  /tmp
/dev/sda2           410G     50G   340G  13%  /media/aceryohan
tmpfs               392M     60K   392M   1%  /run/user/1000

I also tried with pip3 but it returns the same results
Apparently there is still place in all the partitions. Does anyone have an idea for a solution?
Thanks in advance!
output of LANG=C df -i :
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs            500715    960   499755    1% /run
/dev/sda1       3203072 516774  2686298   17% /
tmpfs            500715      1   500714    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            500715      5   500710    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            500715    201   500514    1% /tmp
/dev/sda2      27328512 321946 27006566    2% /media/aceryohan
tmpfs            100143     91   100052    1% /run/user/1000

with LANG=C df -ah it returns :
df: /run/user/1000/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           392M  1,6M  390M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        48G   28G   18G  62% /
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
cgroup2            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup
pstore             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
bpf                0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
systemd-1          -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
hugetlbfs          0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
fusectl            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       75M   75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1439
/dev/loop4      269M  269M     0 100% /snap/firefox/4650
/dev/loop5      497M  497M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
/dev/loop6      506M  506M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
/dev/loop7       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop8       41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20671
tmpfs           2,0G  351M  1,6G  18% /tmp
/dev/loop9       39M   39M     0 100% /snap/snapd/21759
/dev/sda1        48G   28G   18G  62% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
binfmt_misc        0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/dev/sda2       410G   50G  340G  13% /media/aceryohan
tmpfs           392M   60K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
gvfsd-fuse         0     0     0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
tmpfs           392M  1,6M  390M   1% /run/snapd/ns
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt
/dev/loop10     270M  270M     0 100% /snap/firefox/4793
/dev/loop3       75M   75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1564

Is it useful?
I'm on Lubuntu 22.04.
Output of systemctl status tmp.mount:
● tmp.mount - /tmp
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
     Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2024-08-21 07:37:12 CEST; 6 days ago
      Where: /tmp
       What: tmpfs
       Docs: man:fstab(5)
             man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4527)
     Memory: 4.0K
        CPU: 4ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/tmp.mount

août 21 07:37:12 aceryohan systemd[1]: Mounting /tmp...
août 21 07:37:12 aceryohan systemd[1]: Mounted /tmp.


Try LANG=C df -ah, see if a full partition appears

Whats the output of LANG=C df -i?

I add the outputs of LANG=C df -ah and LANG=C df -i in my original question

You appear to have a rather small /tmp - possibly systemd managed? What is you Ubuntu version, and what is the output of systemctl status tmp.mount?

... for some possible workarounds, see for example Cannot install pip module because there is 'no space' left on device
